imposible establecer la conexion vpn, el servidor de vpn podria no estar disponible (-5)
hace un buen rato que estoy presentando este problema
XX/XX/XXXX
VPN SSL
Unable to establish the VPN connection. The VPN server may be unreachable. (-5)

desintale el fortiClient varias veces y tambien reinicie, incluso configure los TLS del internet explorer para hacer match con la VPN y tampoco me funciono...
se los agradeceria si saben de alguna posible solucion.
PD: tengo esta version de VPN fortiClient 7.2.4

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y esto que tiene que ver con programacion?
